# Django: how to redirect to page with list of newly created objects after form post bulk_create

Tags: django

I have a simple form that allows user to paste csv data with the goal to create multiple model objects at one go.

The form method is 'post'. Action url is a method that calls the django `bulk_create` to create the model objects returning the pks.

Goal: After submission, I want to redirect to page showing a list of the objects corresponding to the pks.

Is that possible?

I have tried:

1. `return render(request, "list_template.html", context={'object_list': objects_with_pks})`, passing the model objects as context data to another template (but there would be danger of duplicate submission upon refresh)
2. Redirect user to a model `DetailView` which contains the pk in the url (but I have more than one pks created)
3. return `HttpResponseRedirect` to a new page with a success message (but I won't be able to pass the pks to the new page)
4. Pass `num = len(pks)` to a new view function that accepts a `num` kwargs in its url and returns the last `num` model objects (but is there a proper way?)

Other ways that I've thought but could not find an answer

1. Can I pass multiple pks in a url? so ListView could set the queryset
2. If not, can querysets in a model `ListView` instance be passed as parameters?
3. Is there a way to transform a POST request to a GET?

I am fairly new to web development and posting questions on stackoverflow. Please comment if its unclear and I'll update. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

@jjxxll- Why would you want to pass multiple pk's to a URL? If you want to view all the inserted objects after the bulk_insert is completed then a simple ListView will do. E.g

```
 class ModelListView(ListView):
        model = Model
        template_name = 'some_form.html"
        paginate_by = 10
 In your some_form.html you will have to loop through the object_list and display the fields e.g 

{% for obj in object_list%}
                        {{obj.name}}
                       {% endfor %}
```

That's it

If you want to view DetailView per object using pk

```
 class ModelDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Model
        template_name = 'some_detail_form.html'
   In your detail_form.html you will have to display the data e.g
        {{object.name}}
        {{object.description}}
```